# How to set a a specific time using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I want to set specific time

I've started this

```
def function():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()).isoformat()[0:8]
    schedule = datetime.time(10, 00, 00)
    if current_time == schedule:
```

I want check if the current_time is 10 o'clock, is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: What is `diatomite`? Do you mean `datetime`?

Comment: @Anand S Kumar is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: @nope yes, like Daniel answered.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for all that complicated code.

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
schedule = datetime.time(10, 00, 00)
current_time == schedule
```

Although that will only be true on the exact microsecond of 10:00:00, which is almost certainly not what you want. Do you perhaps want to check that it is in the hour of ten o'clock? That would be even simpler:

```
datetime.datetime.now().hour == 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.now()

if dt.hour == 10 and dt.minute == 0:
    print "it's time"
```